# Pipe filename from Get-ChildItem into a .csv file

Tags: xml, powershell, csv

I'm currently writing a powershell script that will look for files the end with xyz.xml.  It parses the xml and extracts the needed information into an .csv file.  I also need the name of the xyz.xml file in the .csv file for the information to be effective.  I currently have:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *-xyz.xml | ForEach-Object{
$F_Name = Select-Object Name
[xml]$XYZFILE = Get-Content $_
$TITLE=$XYZFILE.title
$RELEASE=$XYZFILE.release
$VERSION=$XYZFILE.version
$FILEPATH = "INFO.csv"
$FILEEXISTS= Test-Path $FILEPATH
If(FILEEXISTS -eq $False){
$csv = @"
"File Name","Name","Release","Version"
"$F_NAME","$TITLE","$RELEASE","$VERSION"
"@
}
ELSE {
$csv = @"
"$F_NAME","$TITLE","$RELEASE","$VERSION"
"@
}
$csv>>$FILEPATH
}
```

Unfortunately when I run this the column of "File Name" is empty and I'm unsure as to why.  Does anyone have any idea as to why I can't get the actual name the of the file that I'm parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is getting passed into `Select-Object Name`. Since you are using `ForEach-Object`, you will want to pipe the automatic variable `$_`, which contains the current object in the pipeline. Also, you will want to expand the `Name` property so that rather than having an object with a property name, your variable will be a string that is the name.

```
$F_Name = Select-Object Name
```

becomes:

```
$F_Name = $_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

or you could use the dot property notation:

```
$F_Name = $_.Name
```

You script could also be simplified by making an array of objects and then using the `Export-CSV -Append` command to add them to the CSV file.

```
$FILEPATH = "INFO.csv"
Get-ChildItem -Filter *-xyz.xml |
    ForEach-Object {
        [xml]$XYZFILE = Get-Content $_
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            "File Name" = $_.Name
            "Name" = $XYZFILE.title
            "Release" = $XYZFILE.release
            "Version" = $XYZFILE.version
        }
    } |
    Export-CSV $FILEPATH -Append
```

Comment: Thanks @BenH, I'm relatively new to PowerShell so I appreciate the the explanation.